Cryptocurrency scam, can anyone help me?
I received a serious scam from a platform called Lemintero.com, can anyone help me reconstruct the flow of money transfers?
Can anyone track my money if I provide the blockchain of transactions? Please help me, these scammers took all my money. I am not an expert and I got scammed by them.
